# Reinstall TeamCity when Tomcat becomes corrupt

Tags: tomcat, teamcity

I've got a TeamCity 4 installation where tomcat has bit the dust with the following error "The APR Based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows for optimal performance in production environments was not found in java.library path".  It appears this started happening once the JDK was installed on the server to allow for a compile.  The JDK has been removed and the JRE reinstalled but still no go.

My question is should I reinstall TeamCity completely or is there a way to simply reinstall tomcat so I don't hose the configuration?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

we went ahead and created a new Win 2k8 instance and reinstalled.  Multiple reinstallations of Team City and Apache would never resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity stores its data including project configuration under the [data directory](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/TeamCity+Data+Directory). Even if you remove Tomcat and reinstall, it will use the same data. The only thing you may need to change is to put the jdbc connector jar into the web application WEB-INF/lib folder if you are using an external database.

Also, the APR error you mentioned is not an actual error, Tomcat doesn't come with the APR by default, you can install it separately if you want, but it's not necessary for the correct operation. We are not using APR on our production TeamCity installations. If you want to use APR, refer to the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html).

From your original problem description it's impossible to say what's actually wrong as APR is absolutely optional and is not installed by default. Though, Tomcat Windows Service installer has an option to install APR automatically:

[optional APR install http://img395.imageshack.us/img395/5233/snap619.png](http://img395.imageshack.us/img395/5233/snap619.png)

If you will have the problem again, I'd recommend referring to the [Reporting Issues](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Reporting+Issues) document.